# laravel connect redis the other method

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm working with Laravel 5.6.
I have a question, connect redis (predis).
I don't want to connect `redis` with config.
Because redis is changing everytime.
I use zkname.

So I want to connect redis like this `Redis::connect('127.0.0.1',3306)`

But it not work!

I use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;`

**This is connection method**

```
public function connection($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: 'default';

    if ( isset($this->connections[$name]) ) {
        return $this->connections[$name];
    }

    return $this->connections[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Comment: I am interested on *Because redis is changing everytime*, why is that?

Comment: Redis is a cluster and uses name services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged the problem, the key point of this problem is that no configuration file, how to connect redis, check some information found that the client in redis databas.php can be predis or phpredis, 
when predis, redis connection only connection method By way of configuration file;

```
Redis::connection();
```

when phpredis has a connect method can use the specified ip and port mode

```
Redis::connect('127.0.0.1',3306);
```